# How can i check a curent investigation of a company?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, investigation, cftc

I'm interested in crypto, and unfortunately there's what i suspect to be this huge scam going on the market, its called tether, although legally i can't claim it is a scam.

Basically they've had a bunch of investigations by the U.S. Commodity Futures Trading Commission and the United States Department of Justice and others, to the point where im even confused on what investigations are opened, which are close.

What i basically want to know is a list on every investigation/ lawsuit/legal problems that are stacking against the company which is called similar to the coin, Tether Limited, and if its possible informations about the investigation(although im fairly certain that those wouldn't just be provided to the public until the lawsuit ends i guess)

Im not native to America so im very confused about the law "rituals" and day to day bureocracy so a more general answer would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Legal problem" is too vague to be included. "Investigation" needs a bit of refining; "lawsuit" is relatively simple (as long as you mean "actual lawsuit" not "idea that maybe we could sue"). There is no central list of all lawsuits against a given party, but you could theoretically check every jurisdiction to see if there is a lawsuit. That's a really big list, maybe in the millions if you want to be complete. You can use ordinary Google search to find announced lawsuits, typically by government agencies.

Finding investigations is even more difficult: you will not be able to determine what investigations I am conducting. Even determining the existence of investigations by police including e.g. the FBI is hard to do. A government attorney is the one most likely to reveal that they are investigating some party with the intent to sue them. Again, you can't get a complete list, you can use Google to get an indication of who has announced an investigation (your results will generally not say whether the investigation was closed, unless you pursue that question as well).